# Posting to a Web API from a Xamarin Android application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am building a Xamarin Android app that connects to a web api. I want to post a complex object to the api and the receive an object again. It works when I post an object and receive a bool value, but not with receiving a complex object. Also it works when I use it in a Windows Mobile app. This method is in a portable library.
Here is my post method:

```
public static IResponseObject Post<T, TOut>(string url, T BindingModel)
        {
            IResponseObject result;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response =
                    client.PostAsJsonAsync(String.Format("{0}{1}", _base, url), BindingModel).Result;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SuccessResponseObject<TOut>>().Result;
                else
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<BadRequestResponse>().Result;
                ((ResponseObject)result).Status = response.StatusCode;

                return result; 
            }
        }
```

Should I be doing something different for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the post was in a portable library. When I move the method to the main project it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using async / await. That is most likely causing the issue.

Try this extension method:

```
 public static async Task<TOut> PostJsonAsyncPost<T, TOut>this HttpClient client, string url, T param)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, param);

            string content = await result.EnsureSuccessful().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOutput>(content);
        }
```

Then you can just do:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient ()) {
                    var result = await httpClient.PostJsonAsyncPost<T,Out>(url,myobject);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks but I had still no luck with this.